# ERROR_CODE_IO_BAD_HTTP_STATUS exoplayer android

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I've a url of the form `http://x.x.x:80/movie/HqZqUt3I7B/QhGtliO2V4/xxxx.mp4?play_token=6nsYOBGUKj` from where I want to fetch video and display it in exoplayer. I confirmed that url is perfectly working by putting that url in VLC Network Stream. But the same url is not working in exoplayer. Here's my exoplayer initializing code.

```
private fun initializePlayer() {
    if (url.isNotEmpty()){
        player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        binding.videoView.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
        player.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT
        binding.videoView.player = player
        val mediaItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url)
        Log.d("testurl", url)
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        player.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
        player.prepare()
        player.addListener(this)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to play the video!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I've also implemented `OnPlayerError` listener to catch the error.

```
override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
    super.onPlayerError(error)
    if (error.message!=null) {
        Log.d("testmediaerror", "${error.errorCodeName} ${error.message}")
    } else {
        Log.d("testmediaerror", error.errorCodeName)
    }
}
```

So, with this code `if` block in `OnPlayerError` was executed and it displayed the error as `D/testmediaerror: ERROR_CODE_IO_BAD_HTTP_STATUS Source error`. It is also necessary to mention that my server is returning the video with status code `302`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the server for the file and then follow `HTTP 302` redirect - this will result in that actual URL and `HTTP 200` when fetching it. In Exoplayer, there's also a config `allowCrossProtocolRedirects` (it usually not permits redirects from eg. HTTPS to HTTP ...but it should support common redirects).

Comment: How can I set `allowCrossProtocolRedirects`? I've seen various posts regarding this and they are setting MediaSource in `player.prepare(mediaSource)` which is deprecated. And also they are doing something like `val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource()` and in my case it is unable to find the class `ExtractorMediaSource`.

Comment: Following the url redirect actually do the trick. Thanks man!

Comment: @FerozKhan, can you please let us know what changes were made to make it work? Were the changes made in the app or on the backend?

Comment: @AnasAzeem Its been a long but what I remember is that I changed `Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))` to `Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))` . And added the dependency for ScalarsConverterFactory, which is `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'`. And then just send a get request with that retrofit client to the url where you are getting redirected. Then in response, you will get `response.raw().request().url().toString()`.